# Laravel get user phone from db

Tags: php, database, laravel

I got users table with phone row. I'm trying to send SMS then user is activated like that:

```
      public function activate($token)
    {
        User::whereActivationToken($token)->firstOrFail()->confirmEmail();
      $phone = $this->user->phone;

        flash()->success(trans('frontend.account.activated'));

        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('account.home');
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('auth.login');
Sms::send("activated!", function($sms) {
    $sms->to(['$phone']); # The numbers to send to.
});
        }
    }
}
```

But i'm getting error, Trying to get property of non-object. Whats wrong? Thanks for answers guys and please dont be mad, i'm new on laravel.

Comment: Does it show you the error line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error may be coming from this line

```
$phone = $this->user->phone;
```

$user exists nowhere in that function. Perhaps you defined it somewhere else. If that's the case, you can fix it with :

```
$user = User::whereActivationToken($token)->firstOrFail();
$phone = $user->phone;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
$user = User::whereActivationToken($token)->firstOrFail();
$user->confirmEmail();
$phone = $user->phone;
```

Comment: Ok, now i'm not getting any erorrs, but also i'm not getting any sms messages. I think $phone does not represent anything

Comment: @ромМакаров you can always look at the User object using `dd()` helper `dd($user);` to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for helping matte. The proble is here: `Sms::send("activated!", function($sms) {
    $sms->to($phone); # The numbers to send to.
});` if i leave (['$phone']) i'm getting on page just phone tag like: $phone, but if i remove and leaving just ($phone) i'm getting error "Undefined variable: phone". Seems really weird